# Prove that $a_n$ converges to $0$

Tags: real-analysis

Given $a_n$ and $t_n$ are two sequences such that $ |a_n| \leq t_n $ $\forall n$ and $t_n \rightarrow 0$

Let $\epsilon > 0$. so $\forall n>N_1, |t_n| < \epsilon$.
Consider, $|a_n-0| = |a_n| \leq t_n$
But $t_n \leq |t_n|$. so $|a_n| \leq |t_n| < \epsilon $

Not sure if its correct ?

Comment: It's correct. I mean, what do you think might be wrong in this solution? For $\epsilon>0$ you found a corresponding index.

Comment: @Mark i don't know. i am studying analysis all by myself.

Comment: So yes, your solution is correct. By the way, the fact that $|a_n|\leq t_n$ already tells us that $t_n\geq 0$, so we even have $t_n=|t_n|$.

Comment: thank you sir...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. You could however also use the ["Sandwich theorem"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem), which is made specifically for this case of limit: You have $0\leq |a_n|\leq t_n$ and $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} t_n=0$, so you immediatly get that $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} a_n=0$.

Comment: i see thanks...